# Issue with scroll viewer in windows 10 universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollview, windows-10

I am working on a windows 10 universal App.The basic structure of my page is like

```
<Grid>
   <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True">
        <Pivot>
          <PivotItem/>
          <PivotItem/>
          <PivotItem/>
          <PivotItem/>
        </Pivot>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And in my code behind i wrote the event to handle Scroll changed like this

```
   private void MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //My business logic goes here 
    }
```

For each pivot item, there is contents to scroll.

When i run the App what happens is 
    when i tried to scroll from the scroll bar on the right side,my MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged event getting fired but when i tried to scroll with the mouse wheel,the event not getting fired and i was not able to continue.
Please help to find out the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pivot inside your scrollviewer is intercepting your touch and mouse wheel interactions, that is why you are not receiving anything with your mouse wheel.

Placing a pivot within a scrollviewer is really really weird. What behavior are you trying to achieve ? If you want to scroll vertically in each of the pivot items you should place a scrollviewer in each of your PivotItems, not around your pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem i fixed it like this but i hope we find a better way cause it buggy.

```
 private void PivotItem_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.GetCurrentPoint(scrollViewer).Properties.MouseWheelDelta == (-120))
        {
            // On Mouse Wheel scroll Backward
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Height / 10, null, false);
        }
        if (e.GetCurrentPoint(scrollViewer).Properties.MouseWheelDelta == (120))
        {
            // On Mouse Wheel scroll Forward
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(null,scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Height / 10, null, false);
        }
    }
```